# How do you evaluate the limit $\lim_{h\,\to\, 0^{+}}\, \left(\frac{{\rm e}^{-1/h^{2}}\,}{h}\right)$?

Tags: calculus, limits

How do you evaluate this limit? I can't manage to do it, even after manipulating the limit expression in several different ways, and using L'Hôpital's rule.

$$
\lim_{h\,\to\, 0^{+}}\,
\left(\frac{{\rm e}^{-1/h^{2}}\,}{h}\right)
$$

Comment: Hello, welcome to MSE. Please provide the limit you want to solve in the body of your question - I can't see it.

Comment: Having looked at your question via the edit button, I see you want to evaluate $\lim_{h→0^+}(\frac{e^{−1/h^2}}{h})$. I have submitted an edit to reflect this and it should be visible to anyone soon. In future, please format maths on MSE using MathJax rather than images.

Comment: We have a Latex-like typesetting system for mathematical expressions, called MathJax. Information is here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10164

Comment: Recall that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}x^pe^{-x}=0$ for all $p>0$

Answer (score 3):

We wish to evaluate

$$L =\lim _{h \to 0^+} \left(\frac{e^{-{1/h^2}}}{h}\right).$$

Substitute $u = \frac{1}{h}$ to get

$$L =\lim _{u \to \infty} (ue^{-u^2}).$$

We have $0 < ue^{-u^2} < ue^{-{u}}$ for all $u > 1$. (*)

It is a standard result that $\lim _{u \to \infty} (ue^{-u}) = 0.$ (To prove this, consider the Taylor series of $e^{-u}$.)

Thus by taking $u \to \infty$ in (*) we get $0 \leq L \leq 0$.

Hence $L=0$.

Comment: Technically that double inequality you use to squeeze requires $u>1$.

Comment: @J.G. Oops - my bad. Fixed, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score -2):

If you evalute the limit of the inverse by using L'Hopital, and you will find that the limit of the inverse goes to zero as h goes to zero. So the limit should goes to infinity.